# Execute linux command on Centos using dotnet core

Tags: centos, .net-core, tar, lz4

I'm running a .NET Core Console Application on CentOS box. The below code is executing for normal command like `uptime`, but not executing for `lz4 -dc --no-sparse vnp.tar.lz4 | tar xf - Logs.pdf`:

```cs
try
{
    var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("server", "username", new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username", "pwd"));
    using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
    {
        client.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        var command = client.CreateCommand("lz4 -dc --no-sparse vnp.tar | tar xf - Logs.pdf");
        var result = command.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("yup ! UNIX Commands Executed from C#.net Application");
        Console.WriteLine("Response came form UNIX Shell" + result);

        client.Disconnect();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Expected output is Logs.pdf file needs to be extracted and saved in the current location. Can someone correct me where im

Answer (score 15):

If application is running on Linux machine then you can try this also:

```
string command = "write your command here";
string result = "";
using (System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.Start();

    result += proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    result += proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    proc.WaitForExit();
}
return result;
```

Comment: If command contains quotes, you should escape it like `command = command.Replace("\"", "\\\"");`

Comment: If i need the output of the command ls in folder /opt/myFile what should be the values of FileName and Arguments?